Html2Pdf Error [2] Unable to get the size of the image [image1/2.png]
So I have a form whose data is connected to MySQL, specifically the image data is stored in the form/image1 folder, then I want to use that data in my PDF template, but when I try to insert an image an Html2Pdf Error occurs [2]
Unable to get the size of the image [image1/2.png]
The following is the coding of my template
<tr style="height:142pt">
  <td style="width:503pt;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1pt;border-left-style:solid;border-left-width:1pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:1pt" colspan="3">
    <p style="text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"><br/>**<img width="60" height="65" src="'. $row['incident_attachments'] .'" style="float:left;" /**></p>
  </td>
</tr>

I've tried to find out whether the path is wrong or what, but haven't found the answer

Yeah, it's probably the path. I have no idea what it is, or what it should be, only you can tell.

so the image that I put into mysql is saved in the form/image1 folder and I make a call
$incident_attachments = $row['incident_attachments'];
$incident_attachments_path = realpath('../form/image1/' . $incident_attachments);

But you don't use $incident_attachments_path in the code you show in the question.

when i use

error change to
Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\approval_website\vendor\spipu\html2pdf\src\Html2Pdf.php:1520 Stack trace: #0
